# CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_description() on bool (woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i needed to get a [product_description] shortcode to my products (they have a particular structure and tabs wans't right for me)so  added to my functios file this piece of code

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'display_custom_product_description' );
function display_custom_product_description( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'custom_product_description' );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    return $product->get_description();
}
```

work perfect for what i wanted, however; since i got this code i keeo getting this fatal error in logs:

> 2021-03-16T00:00:16+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_description() on bool in /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php:30
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(343): display_custom_product_description(Array, '', 'custom_product_...')
> #1 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
> #2 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(218): preg_replace_callback('/\[(\[?)>>>>(custom...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '\n[custom_produc...')
> #3 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/helpers/helpers-shortcode.php(203): do_shortcode('\n[custom_produc...')
> #4 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/shortcodes/row.php(214): flatsome_contentfix('\n[custom_produc...')
> #5 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(343): ux_col(Array, '\n[custom_produc...', 'col')
> #6 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array)
> #7 /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(218): preg_replace_callback( en /home/evadevcl/public_html/elr/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php en la línea 30

Even though i have search this exact issue i can´t seem to find the solution for it, it is not making any harm (visible or function) in my site but i am kind worried this might brake my site at any time, does anyone could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an initial check to verify that the shortcode only activates on the product page.

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'display_custom_product_description' );
function display_custom_product_description( $atts ){

    // only on the product page
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return;
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_id(),
    ), $atts, 'custom_product_description' );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product') )
        $product = wc_get_product($atts['id']);

    return $product->get_description();
}
```

**If you want to use the shortcode also outside the product page**

You don't have to set the `get_the_id()` value to the **id** attribute of the first parameter otherwise the shortcode will always ignore the product id entered by the user.

> You can use the following shortcode **on any page of the site** by
> setting, in this case, the id attribute with the id of the product you
> want to get the description of.

You can optimize the shortcode like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'custom_product_description', 'display_custom_product_description' );
function display_custom_product_description( $atts ){

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts, 'custom_product_description' );

    if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
        if ( is_product() ) {
            global $product;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if ( is_a( wc_get_product($atts['id']), 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    return $product->get_description();
}
```